# Function "TO_DATE" not found; SQL statement: in H2 database and not using TO_CHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

**Not Duplicate:**
I am getting an error saying `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_DATE" not found; SQL statement:`

What can I replace it with so it will run. I used RazorSql to create mysql from a oracle db. Now I am trying to run it in a H2 database.

mysql causing the error:

```
CREATE TABLE ASSET (
    ASSET_ID DECIMAL(22) NOT NULL,
    SHOP_ID DECIMAL(22) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ID DECIMAL(22) NOT NULL,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
    MODIFIED_AT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
    VALID_FROM datetime DEFAULT to_date('2013-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  NOT NULL,
    VALID_TILL datetime DEFAULT to_date('2113-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ASSET_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can simply do:

```
VALID_FROM datetime DEFAULT '2013-12-01'  NOT NULL,
VALID_TILL datetime DEFAULT '2113-12-01'  NOT NULL,
```

I don't think there is a syntax that will work in both MySQL and Oracle.  Although MySQL does support the `DATE` keyword (as in `DATE '2013-12-01'`), this appears to not be valid as a `DEFAULT` value.